# How to get notified when device's software is upgraded in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an app which checks few things when device software is upgraded. It can be OS upgrade or any kind of upgrade pushed by device manufacturer OTA.

Is it possible to detect when device software is upgraded? Something like broadcast?
I tried this broadcast-

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

but this works only when app is upgraded from play store or upgrading from the package manager. It doesn't work when OS upgrades.